# Can I have a controller with the same name as an area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Let's say I have an area named `Admin` in my MVC application. This area has a `HomeController` with an `Index` action like so:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AreasPractice.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content("Admin.HomeController");
        }

    }
}
```

The area registration for the Admin area has the following defaults for the area related route:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AreasPractice.Areas.Admin
{
    public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Admin";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                //, new[] { "AreasPractice.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

My application's root area also has a `HomeController` with an `Index` action and a route config like so:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AreasPractice.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content("From home controller of the root");
        }
    }
}

public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                , namespaces: new[] { "AreasPractice.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
```

Now, I add an `AdminController` with an `Index` action in the root area of my application like so:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AreasPractice.Controllers
{
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content("Root -> Admin Controller -> Index action.");
        }

    }
}
```

When I run the application, I am expecting to see something interesting, like, may be an exception to the effect, "I can't figure out what route you want."

But when I run the application, it runs just fine and a request for:

`/Admin/`

yields to the `HomeController` in the `Admin` area.

This is because, apparently, and as I recall, the routing mechanism works on a priority basis. It finds the *first match* and goes with it.

And it is apparently finding that the **Admin_default** route satisfies the request pattern even before it applies the **Default** route.

My question(s):

1. Is my understanding so far correct?
2. What do I do to play with it? What if I want it to go to the
       AdminController in the root area of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got the answer after some more thinking. If I just moved the area registration in the global.asax file to *after* the default route has been registered, it now goes to the `AdminController` of my root instead of going to the `Admin` area's `HomeController`.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            // Remove from here
            // AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            // Put here after the default route has been 
            // registered via the RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes 
            // call above
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        }
    }
```